# Invoke Java from C++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to invoke the Java Virtual machine from C++ following the example found [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html#11202):

Basically I have a small Java program:

```
public class TestJNIInvoke
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Then I have a C++ program that I want to create a JVM and call the `TestJNIInvoke` class:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define PATH_SEPARATOR ';' /* define it to be ':' on Solaris */
#define USER_CLASSPATH "." /* where Prog.class is */

using namespace std;

int main() {
     JNIEnv *env;
     JavaVM *jvm;
     jint res;
     jclass cls;
     jmethodID mid;
     jstring jstr;
     jclass stringClass;
     jobjectArray args;

 #ifdef JNI_VERSION_1_2
     JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
     JavaVMOption options[1];
     options[0].optionString =
         "-Djava.class.path=" USER_CLASSPATH;
     vm_args.version = 0x00010002;
     vm_args.options = options;
     vm_args.nOptions = 1;
     vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
     /* Create the Java VM */
     res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
 #else
     JDK1_1InitArgs vm_args;
     char classpath[1024];
     vm_args.version = 0x00010001;
     JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);
     /* Append USER_CLASSPATH to the default system class path */
     sprintf(classpath, "%s%c%s",
             vm_args.classpath, PATH_SEPARATOR, USER_CLASSPATH);
     vm_args.classpath = classpath;
     /* Create the Java VM */
     res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &vm_args);
 #endif /* JNI_VERSION_1_2 */

     if (res < 0) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Can't create Java VM\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "TestJNIInvoke");
     if (cls == NULL) {
         goto destroy;
     }

     mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "main",
                                     "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
     if (mid == NULL) {
         goto destroy;
     }
     jstr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, " from CPP!");
     if (jstr == NULL) {
         goto destroy;
     }
     stringClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
     args = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 1, stringClass, jstr);
     if (args == NULL) {
         goto destroy;
     }
     (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, cls, mid, args);

 destroy:
     if ((*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env)) {
         (*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);
     }
     (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
 }
```

But When I try to compile the C++ program I get this error:

```
c:\java\JNI> g++ -I"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\include"-I"c:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\win32" -c TestJNIInvoke.cpp


TestJNIInvoke.cpp: In function 'int main()':
TestJNIInvoke.cpp:20:31: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to
'char*'
TestJNIInvoke.cpp:44:18: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEn
v'
TestJNIInvoke.cpp:49:18: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEn
v'
TestJNIInvoke.cpp:54:19: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEn
v'
TestJNIInvoke.cpp:58:26: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEn
v'
TestJNIInvoke.cpp:59:19: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEn
v'
TestJNIInvoke.cpp:63:12: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEn
v'
TestJNIInvoke.cpp:66:16: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEn
v'
TestJNIInvoke.cpp:67:16: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JNIEn
v'
TestJNIInvoke.cpp:69:12: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'JavaVM'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You should include a comment about what is not working with your code. Do you get an error or does it just not work?

Comment: I don't know anything about invoking Java from C++, but you declared `env` as a pointer (`JNIEnv *env`), so of course when you do `(*env)->anything` it will complain because `*env` is not a pointer.  Try `env->anything`.

Comment: Or alternatively: use the dot (`.`) operator instead of the arrow (`->`). The same problem occurs with the JVM object, too: `(*jvm)`. Additionally somewhere a string literal is *implicitly* cast to `char*`, so you might want to make this cast _explicit_ instead. (This will get rid of the warning).

Comment: I see your code is essentially the same as what Sun has posted on their site. Are you using the same version of Java as the example? What if you find a different example of using JNI?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Even though you include the same header file, the Java Native Interface uses two different interfaces for C and C++.

In C++, it's:

```
jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
```

instead of (for C):

```
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
```

So the C function call that requires `env` in two places becomes a convenient member function call in C++.

This is mentioned in the [Native Method Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp715) section of the [Java Native Interface 6.0 Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that there were different interfaces. This will make my life a lot easier. :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you're attempting to compile against the win32 headers given the command line you're using. Have you tried `-I"c:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0\include\solaris` instead (assuming that's your platform based on the comment higher up in the source).

Comment: It's not an issue of headers, it's an issue of incorrect syntax. Syntax for accessing members/methods of objects via pointer (->) is used where values are supplied through pointer dereferencing (*env).

Comment: Ah, sorry, agreed. I didn't spot the scrollbar and only looked at the code at the top of the snippet which didn't include any of the problem code.